# Lightweight ruby framework on raspberry pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm looking for fast and light ruby framework to build a web server on Raspberry Pi. This should be mostly <10 pages site + api service and for up to 3 users.

I'm tried to use rails with [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) but it was to heavy. It took ~ 16 secs to load up one of pages from this [app](https://github.com/brbrr/sample_app).

So I need some light ruby framework, or ideas how to make rails fast and less resource consuming.

Here is rails request timings:

```
  Rendered shared/_feed_item.html.erb (1399.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (1515.6ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1716.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (17.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 1936ms (Views: 1803.6ms | ActiveRecord: 67.4ms)
```

Comment: You can use Ruby on Rails with no problem. Obviously - as with all programming languages - you can write slow and fast code.

Comment: @wintermeyer yup, but i'm not sure that rails is a best choice for 500mb RAM arm pc. + I'm not an developer, so have no such felling like fast code etc

Comment: Give it a try. If It is not fast enough you still have the option to learn assembler or buy a faster hardware. Pro-Tip: Caching is often a big performance boost.

Comment: I already did. I put some number in to post. But anyway, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Watch this talk: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2453-railsconf2013-cache-cash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) a try, it's extremely lightweight and I've used it a lot in situations where I needed minimal resource usage. There are gems you can use to add Rails like components such as Active Record to it as needed.

Alternatively it sounds like you might be running Rails in development mode, this will be much slower because in `development.rb` `cache_classes` will be set to `false` so classes are reloaded on every request. If that's the case, try changing `cache_classes` to `true` and restarting the server.